# How do I use chained javascript prototype inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototype, scope, this, prototyping

```
function Entity() {
    this.a = {a: 4};
    this.b = 5;
}

function Thing() {}
Thing.prototype = new Entity;

var thing1 = new Thing;
thing1.a.a = 3;
thing1.b = 4;
var thing2 = new Thing;
console.log(thing2.a.a); // prints 3 instead of 4. I would like 4.
console.log(thing2.b) // prints 5 as wanted
```

I'm having difficulty with setting prototypical inheritance in javascript. Ideally I want both thing1 and thing2 to have their own clean copy of the "new Entity prototype".

using `this.__proto__` is something I want to avoid

[Edit]

I have a rough idea of how this working.

Setting thing1.b sets the b property on the Thing instance. which does not touch the Entity.b defined in the prototype chain.

Where as setting thing1.a.a on the Thing instance cannot been done because it would throw an "cannot set a on undefined" error. *That's* when it goes up the prototype chain to find Entity.a which is defined and sets Entity.a.a to a new value.

[Further Edit]

As @IvoWetzel says setting thing1.b does not touch the prototype chain because setting properties does not. Where as setting thing1.a.a does two steps. A *getter* on thing1.a which touches the prototype chain followed by a setter of .a

Comment: Can you use less confusing variable names please? Perhaps don't reuse a and b for both member and global variables. Try foo, bar, baz or something else.

Comment: I used something slightly more sensible. Probably wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A thing you could do is to *apply* the logic of your `Entity` constructor inside `Thing`, for example:

```
function Entity() {
    this.a = {a: 4};
    this.b = 5;
}
Entity.prototype.c = 6;

function Thing() {
  Entity.apply(this, arguments); // ejecutes the assignments made in Entity
}
Thing.prototype = new Entity;

var a = new Thing;
a.a.a = 3;

var b = new Thing;
console.log(a.a.a); // 3
console.log(b.a.a); // 4

console.log(a.b);   // 5
console.log(b.b);   // 5

console.log(a.c);   // 6
console.log(b.c);   // 6
```

Comment: That solves the issue but doesnt explain why a.a.a references something inside new Entity object where as a.a & a.b reference something inside the new Thing object

Comment: If you consider that the OP is asking for prototypes to behave like classes, then it makes sense that the OP should be calling the superclass constructor, which is what this equates to.

Comment: It does, really; with `.a.a`, you're setting a value inside an object, so the object is shared, whereas with `.b` you're reassigning the value.  It's standard by-reference and by-value stuff common in almost all languages. And calling super in that way is the proper way to do it.

Comment: With that, also be aware that in constructing Thing.prototype you are calling the Entity constructor; if it shouldn't be run twice, you should do something like this: `function tmp(){};tmp.prototype=Entity.prototype;Thing.prototype = new tmp()`. That's the technique used in common libraries as it avoids the constructor call while still getting the prototype chain right (again, because the `.prototype` stuff is by reference, not by value).

Comment: @ChrisMorgan the constructor should be called once per creation of a Thing instance so that is the intended behaviour. Doing `Thing.prototype = new Entity` is a mistake that will be replaced with `Thing.prototype = Entity.prototype`

Comment: @Raynos: DON'T do `Thing.prototype = Entity.prototype` - then the prototypes will be the same object. That's *why* `Thing.prototype = new tmp()` is used. You don't want `Thing.prototype.a = 1` to affect `Entity.prototype.a`!

Answer (score 2):

While CMS has posted a solution, why does `thing2.b` return 5 and why does `thing2.a.a` resolve to the object?

```
var thing1 = new Thing;

// thing1 has no a, but the prototype has so a.a is essentially the a of Entity
thing1.a.a = 3;

// Sets b on thing1, setting does not go up the prototype chain(!)
thing1.b = 4;  

// that's what thing1 looks like
Thing {proto: Entity { 
                      a: { <--- gets resolved 
                          a: 3 <-- gets set
                      }, 
                      b: 5
              },
              b: 4 <-- gets set directly
      }


var thing2 = new Thing;

// thing2.a does not exist, so we look up the prototype and find a on Entity
console.log(thing2.a.a); 

// thing2.b also does not exists, so once again we look up the prototype to find b on Entity
console.log(thing2.b);

// that's what thing2 looks like
Thing {proto: Entity {
                      a: {
                          a: 3 <- gets resolved
                      },
                      b: 5 <- gets resolved
              }
      }
```

All the trouble is about JavaScript going up the prototype chain in order to find properties. But when you set properties it **does not** go up the chain.

Comment: Why does a.a.a not set a.a on Thing? Thats what im really wondering.

Answer (score 0):

That's because JavaScript objects are always treated as references.

Therefore when you change the `this.a` object by doing `a.a.a = 3;` you're changing that one object in memory. New instances of `Thing` will reference that same object in memory because the `Entity` constructor is not called every time `Thing` is, and the `this.a` object remains the same.

I would put `this.a` outside the prototype chain, probably directly inside the `Thing` constructor. This would make it so that a new version of `this.a` is created in memory every time `Thing` is instantiated.

Comment: this.a is in the Entity constructor.